# Vocabulary trainer passing around too much IO/State

Tags: haskell, io, quiz, state

I've written a vocabulary trainer which does a lot of passing state around, as I have an ACID-database and a temporary state.

In my experience with Haskell I've learnt that overusing `IO ()` is a code smell,
I think that this is also true for state.

Please have a look at the following `Main.hs`, which is improvable in my opinion.
The whole project is available at GitHub; feel free to clone it. [git clone](https://github.com/epsilonhalbe/VocabuLambda.git)

```
module Main (main) where

import VocabularyData
import Database
import FreqTable
import Trainer

import Control.Exception (bracket)
import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Data.Acid
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)
import Data.Char (toUpper)
import System.Exit (exitSuccess)
import System.IO (hFlush, stdout)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let test = initTestState
    lang <- getSourceOrTarget "from"
    test' <- execStateT (source.=lang) test
    lang' <- getSourceOrTarget "to"
    test'' <- execStateT (target.=lang') test'
    bracket (openLocalState emptyLearntList)
            (closeAcidState)
            (\db -> command db test'')

command :: AcidState LearntList -> TestState -> IO ()
command db test = do putStrLn "+===================================================+"
                     putStrLn "|                                                   |"
                     putStrLn "| what to do next? (type: \"help\" for help screen)   |"
                     putStrLn "|                                                   |"
                     putStrLn "+===================================================+"
                     cmd <- getLine
                     control db test cmd

control :: AcidState LearntList -> TestState -> String -> IO ()
control db test "help"          = do print_help
                                     command db test

control db test "next"          = do len <- query db LengthVocabulary
                                     if (len <=0)
                                       then do putStrLn "No vocabulary in list."
                                               putStrLn "Use \"add word\" to insert."
                                               command db test
                                       else do idx <- randomListIndex (fromIntegral len)
                                               f   <- query db (LookupFrequency idx)
                                               test' <- execStateT (currentWord.=freqTable!!(f-1)) test
                                               -- putStrLn $ "vocabulary list len: "++show len      --   _   _  _       _  --
                                               -- putStrLn $ "random index: "++show idx             --  | \ |_ |_⟩ | | | _ --
                                               -- putStrLn $ "frequency to the index: "++show       --  |_/ |_ |_⟩ |_| |_| --
                                               -- print test'                                       --                     --
                                               guess db test'

control db test "change source" = do lang <- getSourceOrTarget "from"
                                     test' <- execStateT (source.=lang) test
                                     -- print test'
                                     command db test'

control db test "change target" = do lang <- getSourceOrTarget "to"
                                     test' <- execStateT (target.=lang) test
                                     -- print test'
                                     command db test'

control db test ('a':'d':'d':' ':'w':'o':'r':'d':xs) =
    do let times = maybeRead xs :: Maybe Int
       _repeat db test times

control db test "clear all"     = do putStrLn "Are you sure to delete all learnt vocabularies?"
                                     putStrLn "Type \"yes\" or \"no\" to confirm."
                                     yesNo <- getLine
                                     yesNoElse db test yesNo

control db _    "exit"          = do closeAcidState db
                                     exitSuccess

control db test "print db"      = do frqKnowList <- query db ViewAllVocabulary
                                     print frqKnowList
                                     command db test

control db test _               = do putStrLn "Invalid Input"
                                     command db test

guess :: AcidState LearntList -> TestState -> IO ()
guess db test = do putStr $ "What is ("++show (test^.source)++"): "
                   putStrLn $ vocab (test^.currentWord) (test^.source)
                   putStr $ "Your answer ("++show (test^.target)++") is: "
                   hFlush stdout
                   answer <- getLine
                   let is_hinted = (test^.hinted)
                       is_correct = correct (test^.currentWord) (test^.target) answer
                       f = test^.currentWord.frq
                   if is_hinted
                     then if is_correct
                             then do _ <- update db (UpdateKnowledge f 3)
                                     putStrLn "Correct, +3 Knowledge!"
                                     putStr "Full Answer: "
                                     putStrLn (vocab (test^.currentWord) (test^.target))
                                     command db test
                             else do _ <- update db (UpdateKnowledge f (-2))
                                     putStrLn "Wrong, -2 Knowledge!"
                                     putStr "Correct Answer: "
                                     putStrLn (vocab (test^.currentWord) (test^.target))
                                     test' <- execStateT (hinted.=False) test
                                     command db test'
                     else if is_correct
                             then do _ <- update db (UpdateKnowledge f 5)
                                     putStrLn "Correct, +5 Knowledge!"
                                     putStr "Full Answer: "
                                     putStrLn (vocab (test^.currentWord) (test^.target))
                                     command db test
                             else do test' <- execStateT (hinted.=True) test
                                     putStr "Hint: "
                                     putStrLn (hint (test'^.currentWord) (test'^.source))
                                     guess db test'


_repeat :: AcidState LearntList -> TestState -> Maybe Int -> IO ()
_repeat db test (Just n)| n<=0 = command db test
                                | otherwise = do _ <- update db AddVocabulary
                                                 _repeat db test (Just (n-1))
_repeat db test Nothing = do _ <- update db AddVocabulary
                             command db test


yesNoElse :: AcidState LearntList -> TestState -> String -> IO ()
yesNoElse db test "yes" = do _ <- update db ClearVocabulary;command db test
yesNoElse db test "no"  = command db test
yesNoElse db test  _    = control db test "clear all"

print_help :: IO ()
print_help = do putStrLn ""
                putStr "| |_| |" ; putStrLn "help          -> prints this text"
                putStr "| | | |" ; putStrLn ""
                putStr "|  _  |" ; putStrLn "next          -> next random vocabulary"
                putStr "| |_  |" ; putStrLn "add word      -> adds a new vocabulary to the list of learnt words"
                putStr "| |_  |" ; putStrLn "clear all     -> clears all vocabulary from the list of learnt words"
                putStr "|     |" ; putStrLn ""
                putStr "| |   |" ; putStrLn "change source -> changes the source language"
                putStr "| |_  |" ; putStrLn "change target -> changes the target language"
                putStr "|  _  |" ; putStrLn ""
                putStr "| |_| |" ; putStrLn "print db      -> prints the database"
                putStr "| |   |" ; putStrLn "exit          -> guess what \"exits the program\""
--                 putStrLn "print test    -> prints the current test"
initTestState :: TestState
initTestState = TestState { _currentWord = freqTable!!0
                          , _source      = F
                          , _target      = D
                          , _hinted      = False }

langOptions :: IO ()
langOptions = do putStrLn "\tF/f for Français/French/Französisch"
                 putStrLn "\tD/d for Allemande/German/Deutsch"
                 putStrLn "\tE/e for Anglais/English/Englisch"

getSourceOrTarget :: String -> IO Language
getSourceOrTarget toOrFrom = do
    putStrLn $ "Which language do you want to translate "++toOrFrom++"?"
    langOptions
    lang <- getLine
    case (maybeRead . map toUpper . take 1) lang of Just l  -> return l
                                                    Nothing -> do putStrLn "Invalid Input"
                                                                  getSourceOrTarget toOrFrom

maybeRead :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
maybeRead = fmap fst . listToMaybe . reads

hint :: Word -> Language -> String
hint w F = w^.phrase
hint w D = w^.satz
hint w E = w^.sentence

vocab :: Word-> Language -> String
vocab w F = w^.fra
vocab w D = w^.deu
vocab w E = w^.eng

correct :: Word-> Language -> String -> Bool
correct w F str = elem str $ (subst2 . words . subst) (w^.fra)
correct w D str = elem str $ (subst2 . words . subst) (w^.deu)
correct w E str = elem str $ (subst2 . words . subst) (w^.eng)

subst ::String -> String
subst = map subst_
      where subst_ :: Char -> Char
            subst_ ';' = ' '
            subst_ '.' = ' '
            subst_ ',' = ' '
            subst_ '/' = ' '
            subst_ a = a

subst2 :: [String] -> [String]
subst2 = map (map subst_)
       where subst_ :: Char -> Char
             subst_ '_' = ' '
             subst_ a = a
```

Comment: I believe the _prompt_ monad would be an answer to your problem. See [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fa.haskell/XfX6LKlpheA) and [this paper](http://web.mit.edu/~ezyang/Public/threemonads.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a few suggestions:

1. Instead of functions recursively call each other, have a single master dispatching function that calls `command`, `control`, `guess` etc. This will give a central overview how the whole process works. Otherwise it's very difficult to comprehend the flow of the program.
2. Pattern matching on `String`s is very error prone and you can't give meaningful error messages if a user types a wrong command. So instead I'd suggest to introduce a data type that holds all possible user commands and create a parser that parses user input into commands (for example using *parsec*). Something like

   ```
   data Command = Help | Next | AddWords Int | ...
   ```
3. There are many options how to avoid having everything inside `IO`. One possibility is to use the prompt monad (see my comment). As an example, let's modify `guess` using `MonadPrompt`. First, we'll create a data type that represents all possible actions `guess` can perform:

   ```
   data GuessPrompt a where
       AskWord           :: String -> GuessPrompt String
       Say               :: String -> GuessPrompt ()
       DbUpdateKnowledge :: Int -> Int -> GuessPrompt ()
       AltTestState      :: State TestState a -> GuessPrompt a
   ```

   (we'll need [GADTs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Generalised_algebraic_datatype) for this). Each constructor represents an action that takes a given set of parameters and returns some result to the caller. It will be convenient to have corresponding helper functions so that we don't have to write `prompt . ...` everywhere:

   ```
   askWord                 = prompt . AskWord
   say                     = prompt . Say
   dbUpdateKnowledge f n   = prompt (DbUpdateKnowledge f n)
   altTestState            = prompt . AltTestState
   ```

   Now we can rewrite `guess` as follows. It doesn't carry around any state nor database and runs in any monad that is an instance of `MonadPrompt GuessPrompt` (this signature requires [FlexibleContexts](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/FlexibleContexts)).

   ```
   import Control.Monad.State as S (MonadState(..))
   -- ...

   guess' :: (MonadPrompt GuessPrompt m) => m ()
   guess' = do
       test <- altTestState S.get
       answer <- askWord $ "What is ("++show (test^.source)++"): " ++
                           vocab (test^.currentWord) (test^.source) ++ "\n" ++
                           "Your answer ("++show (test^.target)++") is: "
       let is_hinted = (test^.hinted)
           is_correct = correct (test^.currentWord) (test^.target) answer
           f = test^.currentWord.frq
       if is_hinted
         then if is_correct
           then do
             dbUpdateKnowledge f 3
             say $ "Correct, +3 Knowledge!\n" ++
                    "Full Answer: " ++
                    (vocab (test^.currentWord) (test^.target)) ++ "\n" ++
                    "Translated Hint: " ++
                    hint (test^.currentWord) (test^.target)
             altTestState $ hinted.=False
           else do
             dbUpdateKnowledge f (-2)
             say $ "Wrong, -2 Knowledge!\n" ++
                    "Correct Answer: " ++
                    vocab (test^.currentWord) (test^.target) ++ "\n" ++
                    "Translated Hint: " ++
                    hint (test^.currentWord) (test^.target)
             altTestState $ hinted.=False
         else if is_correct
           then do
             dbUpdateKnowledge f 5
             say $ "Correct, +5 Knowledge!\n" ++
                    "Full Answer: " ++
                    vocab (test^.currentWord) (test^.target)
           else do
             test' <- altTestState $ hinted.=True >> S.get
             say $ "Hint: " ++
                   hint (test'^.currentWord) (test'^.source)
             guess'
   ```

   Now `guess'` has no reference to `IO` or other particular monad, it only uses our given set of actions. For example, we could create a testing instance that simulates user input, checks that it returns (`Say`s) the correct reply, checks how `guess'` updates the database etc.

   If we converted the whole `Main` module, we'd most likely add all the actions our functions need and we'd let the main dispatcher provide the correct implementations. Since we converted only `guess`, we could implement the old `guess` type as

   ```
   guess :: AcidState LearntList -> TestState -> IO ()
   guess db test = evalStateT (runPromptM actions guess') test
     where
       actions :: GuessPrompt a -> StateT TestState IO a
       actions (AskWord msg)           = lift $ putStrLn msg >> getLine
       actions (Say msg)               = lift $ putStrLn msg
       actions (DbUpdateKnowledge f n) = lift $ update db (UpdateKnowledge f n)
       actions (AltTestState s)        = mapStateT (return . runIdentity) s
   ```

   which describes in one place how the actions are actually executed inside `IO` and `TestState`.